# What is a 'icarus' set?

Tags: set-theory, definition, large-cardinals

I've been hearing about the Icarus set on the internet recently, and I've been wondering what is it? I've searched the internet and there isn't really an explanation for it. The most I know about the set is that it is extremely large and that it is somewhat related to large cardinals.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/420386/320040

Comment: Where have you heard about Icarus sets, without being given a definition?

Answer (score 2):

An Icarus set is a set that figures in an embedding that lies between $j: L(V_{\lambda+1}) \rightarrow L(V_{\lambda+1})$ and $j: V_{\lambda+2} \rightarrow V_{\lambda+2}$, something generally of the form $j: L(V_{\lambda+1}, N) \rightarrow L(V_{\lambda+1}, N)$, such that $N$ is Icarus. In terms of the [Kunen wall](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Kunen_inconsistency), the reason for the upper bracket being the double powerset for $V_{\lambda}$ is that this stage of the cumulative hierarchy is where the wall first specifically appears (i.e., embedding that stage into itself would break the wall). So the metaphor of $N$ having the Icarus property is, "$N$ is large enough to risk colliding with the transcendent fire of (ZFC) inconsistency."

A common (I don't know if it's exclusive) example (by type) of these $N$ are [sharps such as ${V_{\lambda+1}}^{\sharp}$](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/L_of_V_lambda%2B1#strengthenings-of-texti0-and-woodins-e_alphav_lambda1-sequence), etc. So we'd have embeddings like $j: L(V_{\lambda+1}, {V_{\lambda+1}}^{\sharp}) \rightarrow L(V_{\lambda+1}, {V_{\lambda+1}}^{\sharp})$.

Dimonte[[17](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02613.pdf)] is a good source for an in-depth look at the topic.